# ffmpeg: How to get the same filename for the outfile automatically

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

With `ffmpeg -i inName.mp3 outName.avi` I can create an avi-outfile from a *single*-mp3-infile. 
But how can I get the *same filename* for the outfile automatically (here this would be `inName.avi`)?

Hint: at a loop this works with 
`ffmpeg for %i in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -i "%i" "%~ni.avi"` 
But I do not know how to use the 'auto-filename' at a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I do not know how to use the 'auto-filename' at a single file.

> ```
> ffmpeg for %i in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -i "%i" "%~ni.avi"
> ```

You can just loop over a single file:

```
for %i in (inName.mp3) do ffmpeg -i "%i" "%~ni.avi"
```

Comment: I tested that `ffmpeg for %i in (inName.mp3) do ffmpeg -i "%i" "%~ni.avi"` but I got 

`%i: No such file or directory`

Comment: @cis Answer corrected - remove `ffmpeg` from the start of the line

Comment: Ahh, I understand. My mistake.  Could you help me with the correct syntax at a file named `01. This is the Filename.mp3` I tried several varaiants of `for %i in ("01. This is the Filename.mp3") do ffmpeg -i "%i" "%~ni.avi"`   But he says  `01.: No such file or directory`

Comment: Remove the quotes from `"%1"` - the filename is already quoted

Comment: Ah, TYVM........